# How to write IF statement on percentage floating values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have percentage floating values in column A and also simple numbers in column B (example below):

```
Col A     Col B
25.7%     25000
```

I am trying to find where the col B value is higher than 10k and lower in percentage 3.0 (but it's throwing blank cells) and the function i am using is:

```
=IF(B2>10000*(AND(A2<3));"Y";"")
```

Also, the percentages are in floating numbers so not sure how to nest a floating value in an IF statement `(if(A2>3.0%))` without getting a #value error. I tried nesting it in a round function but that didn't help either.

Can anyone share how percentage floating values can be nested in IF statements?

Comment: `=IF(AND(B2>10000;A2<0.03);"Y";"")` should do what you asked for.

Comment: My excel doesn't accept the 0.03 value. I have tried it before so how to get around the dot is to add an apostrophe but I couldn't find anyway to get around that error.

Comment: Use whatever you use as a decimal point - perhaps a comma: `=IF(AND(B2>10000;A2<0,03);"Y";"")`

Answer (score 0):

Take another look at the syntax for `AND` statements.

It goes before both arguments.

Your % can just be its actual value.

For example:

`=IF(AND(B2>10000,A2<0.03),"Y","")`

Comment: The issue is with the excel not accepting 0.03. Even a simple =IF(G2<0.03;"Y";"") is throwing error to me that you probably need to add an apostrophe somewhere.

Comment: I have updated the formula in the answer, try it now.